# Expression to reflect the Row Group value with each page break in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sqlreportingservice

Sorry if this seems vague; but ive never posted before. Below is a picture for reference:

[Reference Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZz8L.png)

Im trying to do group by Full name and have page breaks to separate each person to their own page. I want to have the specific persons (Provider Name) whos page were on information in cells (Not headers) at the start of every new page. Is there an expression that will pull the value of the current Row Group value for each page?

Answer (score 0):

If you don;t already have a row group that groups by Provider Name then you'll need to add one. Then inside that group, add additional rows as required (this will be two rows in total looking at your design) and add the required data. Then go to the group's properties and set the page breaks to 'between each instance'.

This will force a page break on change of provider and include the group header.